# Scope inheritance in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angular application in a view i am using a template where I have a form.
If I try to change the model from the front-end(view) it doesn't give the updated value in controller but if I bind a function on ng-click and pass the same model in that function than, it is giving me the updated value.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control pl30" placeholder="" required ng-model="amount_seeking" id="amount_seeking" >
```

Suppose I initialize it by

```
$scope.amount_seeking = 1000
```

Now if I change it from front-end and make it 10000, it will again return 1000
on console.log but if I pass it in the function on ng-click then it will give me the updated value.

I understand there is some issue with the inheritance with the parent scope but i didn't got why is this happening.

P.S. : This problem is solved if I use it like $scope.a.amount_seeking

Comment: read [Understanding scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) basically, `amount_seeking` is a primitive. Which is being dereferenced by your click function. Thus referencing  it through the object `a` works fine.

Comment: Could you possibly post some more of your source?  Are you accidentally overwriting the value of amount_seeking before you log it?